# Worklight Application Framework Data Object from Service WSDL errors

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-waf

Using Worklight V6.1 I wanted to try out the new Worklight Application Framework Editor.

My service is a SOAP Webservice and I have the WSDL for the service. I select the Service type of WSDL and add the wsdl file (Copied into the source code window at the bottom of this post) to the dialog.

Then I get my first error saying:

```
Could not find element definition within schema for :{http://www.DFH0XCMN.DFH0XCP4.Response.com} DFH0XCMNOperationResponse
```

Despite this error it seems I can continue to unwrap the details view to show the Input variables, but what the main problem is - there is no Output variables detected. This means if I was following the guide:

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/09_09_Creating_an_application_with_IBM_Worklight_Application_Framework.pdf

When it comes to binding GUI objects to service objects I have no response variables to draw lines between - which means I cannot follow it through to the end.

Please can you advise what is wrong with my WSDL which means that the schema cannot be found - and why Output variables are not detected within the wizard. If we can manually alter the WSDL to make it work - then I would also be interested in what these alterations would be.

The WSDL xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!-- 
<copyright 
 notice="cics-lm-source-program" 
 pids="5655-Y04" 
 years="2009,2013" 
 crc="3891213381" > 


 Licensed Materials - Property of IBM 

 5655-Y04 

 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2009, 2013 All Rights Reserved. 

 US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or 
 disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with 
 IBM Corp. 

 @{[**]copyright.years=2009, 2013} 


 </copyright> 
-->
<definitions targetNamespace="http://www.DFH0XCMN.DFH0XCP4.com" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:reqns="http://www.DFH0XCMN.DFH0XCP4.Request.com" xmlns:resns="http://www.DFH0XCMN.DFH0XCP4.Response.com" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://www.DFH0XCMN.DFH0XCP4.com">
   <types>
      <xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.DFH0XCMN.DFH0XCP4.Request.com" xmlns:tns="http://www.DFH0XCMN.DFH0XCP4.Request.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
         <xsd:complexType abstract="false" block="#all" final="#all" mixed="false" name="ProgramInterface">
            <xsd:annotation>
               <xsd:documentation source="http://www.ibm.com/software/htp/cics/annotations">This schema was generated for use with CICS.</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element name="ca_request_id" nillable="false">
                  <xsd:simpleType>
                     <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:appinfo source="http://www.ibm.com/software/htp/cics/annotations">#Wed Sep 14 08:27:40 BST 2005
com.ibm.cics.wsdl.properties.synchronized=false
</xsd:appinfo>
                     </xsd:annotation>
                     <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:maxLength value="6"/>
                        <xsd:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
                     </xsd:restriction>
                  </xsd:simpleType>
               </xsd:element>
               <xsd:element name="ca_return_code" nillable="false">
                  <xsd:simpleType>
                     <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:appinfo source="http://www.ibm.com/software/htp/cics/annotations">#Wed Sep 14 08:27:40 BST 2005
com.ibm.cics.wsdl.properties.synchronized=false
</xsd:appinfo>
                     </xsd:annotation>
                     <xsd:restriction base="xsd:unsignedShort">
                        <xsd:maxInclusive value="99"/>
                        <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
                     </xsd:restriction>
                  </xsd:simpleType>
               </xsd:element>
               <xsd:element name="ca_response_message" nillable="false">
                  <xsd:simpleType>
                     <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:appinfo source="http://www.ibm.com/software/htp/cics/annotations">#Wed Sep 14 08:27:40 BST 2005
com.ibm.cics.wsdl.properties.synchronized=false
</xsd:appinfo>
                     </xsd:annotation>
                     <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:maxLength value="79"/>
                        <xsd:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
                     </xsd:restriction>
                  </xsd:simpleType>
               </xsd:element>
               <xsd:element name="ca_inquire_single" nillable="false">
                  <xsd:complexType mixed="false">
                     <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="ca_item_ref_req" nillable="false">
                           <xsd:simpleType>
                              <xsd:annotation>
                                 <xsd:appinfo source="http://www.ibm.com/software/htp/cics/annotations">#Wed Sep 14 08:27:41 BST 2005
com.ibm.cics.wsdl.properties.synchronized=false
</xsd:appinfo>
                              </xsd:annotation>
                              <xsd:restriction base="xsd:unsignedShort">
                                 <xsd:maxInclusive value="9999"/>
                                 <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
                              </xsd:restriction>
                           </xsd:simpleType>
                        </xsd:element>
                        <xsd:element name="filler1" nillable="false">
                           <xsd:simpleType>
                              <xsd:annotation>
                                 <xsd:appinfo source="http://www.ibm.com/software/htp/cics/annotations">#Wed Sep 14 08:27:41 BST 2005
com.ibm.cics.wsdl.properties.synchronized=false
</xsd:appinfo>
                              </xsd:annotation>
                              <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                 <xsd:maxLength value="4"/>
                                 <xsd:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
                              </xsd:restriction>
                           </xsd:simpleType>
                        </xsd:element>
                        <xsd:element name="filler2" nillable="false">
                           <xsd:simpleType>
                              <xsd:annotation>
                                 <xsd:appinfo source="http://www.ibm.com/software/htp/cics/annotations">#Wed Sep 14 08:27:41 BST 2005
com.ibm.cics.wsdl.properties.synchronized=false
</xsd:appinfo>
                              </xsd:annotation>
                              <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                 <xsd:maxLength value="3"/>
                                 <xsd:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
                              </xsd:restriction>
                           </xsd:simpleType>
                        </xsd:element>
                        <xsd:element name="ca_single_item" nillable="false">
                           <xsd:complexType mixed="false">
                              <xsd:sequence>
                                 <xsd:element name="ca_sngl_item_ref" nillable="false">
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                       <xsd:annotation>
                                          <xsd:appinfo source="http://www.ibm.com/software/htp/cics/annotations">#Wed Sep 14 08:27:42 BST 2005
com.ibm.cics.wsdl.properties.synchronized=false
</xsd:appinfo>
                                       </xsd:annotation>
                                       <xsd:restriction base="xsd:unsignedShort">
                                          <xsd:maxInclusive value="9999"/>
                                          <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                       </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                 </xsd:element>
                                 <xsd:element name="ca_sngl_description" nillable="false">
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                       <xsd:annotation>
                                          <xsd:appinfo source="http://www.ibm.com/software/htp/cics/annotations">#Wed Sep 14 08:27:43 BST 2005
com.ibm.cics.wsdl.properties.synchronized=false
</xsd:appinfo>
                                       </xsd:annotation>
                                       <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                          <xsd:maxLength value="40"/>
                                          <xsd:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
                                       </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                 </xsd:element>
                                 <xsd:element name="ca_sngl_department" nillable="false">
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                       <xsd:annotation>
                                          <xsd:appinfo source="http://www.ibm.com/software/htp/cics/annotations">#Wed Sep 14 08:27:45 BST 2005
com.ibm.cics.wsdl.properties.synchronized=false
</xsd:appinfo>
                                       </xsd:annotation>
                                       <xsd:restriction base="xsd:unsignedShort">
                                          <xsd:maxInclusive value="999"/>
                                          <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                       </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                 </xsd:element>
                                 <xsd:element name="ca_sngl_cost" nillable="false">
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                       <xsd:annotation>
                                          <xsd:appinfo source="http://www.ibm.com/software/htp/cics/annotations">#Wed Sep 14 08:27:46 BST 2005
com.ibm.cics.wsdl.properties.synchronized=false
</xsd:appinfo>
                                       </xsd:annotation>
                                       <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                          <xsd:maxLength value="6"/>
                                          <xsd:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
                                       </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                 </xsd:element>
                                 <xsd:element name="in_sngl_stock" nillable="false">
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                       <xsd:annotation>
                                          <xsd:appinfo source="http://www.ibm.com/software/htp/cics/annotations">#Wed Sep 14 08:27:48 BST 2005
com.ibm.cics.wsdl.properties.synchronized=false
</xsd:appinfo>
                                       </xsd:annotation>
                                       <xsd:restriction base="xsd:unsignedShort">
                                          <xsd:maxInclusive value="9999"/>
                                          <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                       </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                 </xsd:element>
                                 <xsd:element name="on_sngl_order" nillable="false">
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                       <xsd:annotation>
                                          <xsd:appinfo source="http://www.ibm.com/software/htp/cics/annotations">#Wed Sep 14 08:27:50 BST 2005
com.ibm.cics.wsdl.properties.synchronized=false
</xsd:appinfo>
                                       </xsd:annotation>
                                       <xsd:restriction base="xsd:unsignedShort">
                                          <xsd:maxInclusive value="999"/>
                                          <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                       </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                 </xsd:element>
                              </xsd:sequence>
                           </xsd:complexType>
                        </xsd:element>
                     </xsd:sequence>
                  </xsd:complexType>
               </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
         </xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:element name="DFH0XCMNOperation" nillable="false" type="tns:ProgramInterface"/>
      </xsd:schema>
      <xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.DFH0XCMN.DFH0XCP4.Response.com" xmlns:tns="http://www.DFH0XCMN.DFH0XCP4.Response.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
         <xsd:complexType abstract="false" block="#all" final="#all" mixed="false" name="ProgramInterface">
            <xsd:annotation>
               <xsd:documentation source="http://www.ibm.com/software/htp/cics/annotations">This schema was generated for use with CICS.</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element name="ca_request_id" nillable="false">
                  <xsd:simpleType>
                     <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:appinfo source="http://www.ibm.com/software/htp/cics/annotations">#Wed Sep 14 08:27:58 BST 2005
com.ibm.cics.wsdl.properties.synchronized=false
</xsd:appinfo>
                     </xsd:annotation>
                     <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:maxLength value="6"/>
                        <xsd:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
                     </xsd:restriction>
                  </xsd:simpleType>
               </xsd:element>
               <xsd:element name="ca_return_code" nillable="false">
                  <xsd:simpleType>
                     <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:appinfo source="http://www.ibm.com/software/htp/cics/annotations">#Wed Sep 14 08:27:58 BST 2005
com.ibm.cics.wsdl.properties.synchronized=false
</xsd:appinfo>
                     </xsd:annotation>
                     <xsd:restriction base="xsd:unsignedShort">
                        <xsd:maxInclusive value="99"/>
                        <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
                     </xsd:restriction>
                  </xsd:simpleType>
               </xsd:element>
               <xsd:element name="ca_response_message" nillable="false">
                  <xsd:simpleType>
                     <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:appinfo source="http://www.ibm.com/software/htp/cics/annotations">#Wed Sep 14 08:27:58 BST 2005
com.ibm.cics.wsdl.properties.synchronized=false
</xsd:appinfo>
                     </xsd:annotation>
                     <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:maxLength value="79"/>
                        <xsd:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
                     </xsd:restriction>
                  </xsd:simpleType>
               </xsd:element>
               <xsd:element name="ca_inquire_single" nillable="false">
                  <xsd:complexType mixed="false">
                     <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="ca_item_ref_req" nillable="false">
                           <xsd:simpleType>
                              <xsd:annotation>
                                 <xsd:appinfo source="http://www.ibm.com/software/htp/cics/annotations">#Wed Sep 14 08:27:58 BST 2005
com.ibm.cics.wsdl.properties.synchronized=false
</xsd:appinfo>
                              </xsd:annotation>
                              <xsd:restriction base="xsd:unsignedShort">
                                 <xsd:maxInclusive value="9999"/>
                                 <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
                              </xsd:restriction>
                           </xsd:simpleType>
                        </xsd:element>
                        <xsd:element name="filler1" nillable="false">
                           <xsd:simpleType>
                              <xsd:annotation>
                                 <xsd:appinfo source="http://www.ibm.com/software/htp/cics/annotations">#Wed Sep 14 08:27:58 BST 2005
com.ibm.cics.wsdl.properties.synchronized=false
</xsd:appinfo>
                              </xsd:annotation>
                              <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                 <xsd:maxLength value="4"/>
                                 <xsd:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
                              </xsd:restriction>
                           </xsd:simpleType>
                        </xsd:element>
                        <xsd:element name="filler2" nillable="false">
                           <xsd:simpleType>
                              <xsd:annotation>
                                 <xsd:appinfo source="http://www.ibm.com/software/htp/cics/annotations">#Wed Sep 14 08:27:58 BST 2005
com.ibm.cics.wsdl.properties.synchronized=false
</xsd:appinfo>
                              </xsd:annotation>
                              <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                 <xsd:maxLength value="3"/>
                                 <xsd:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
                              </xsd:restriction>
                           </xsd:simpleType>
                        </xsd:element>
                        <xsd:element name="ca_single_item" nillable="false">
                           <xsd:complexType mixed="false">
                              <xsd:sequence>
                                 <xsd:element name="ca_sngl_item_ref" nillable="false">
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                       <xsd:annotation>
                                          <xsd:appinfo source="http://www.ibm.com/software/htp/cics/annotations">#Wed Sep 14 08:27:59 BST 2005
com.ibm.cics.wsdl.properties.synchronized=false
</xsd:appinfo>
                                       </xsd:annotation>
                                       <xsd:restriction base="xsd:unsignedShort">
                                          <xsd:maxInclusive value="9999"/>
                                          <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                       </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                 </xsd:element>
                                 <xsd:element name="ca_sngl_description" nillable="false">
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                       <xsd:annotation>
                                          <xsd:appinfo source="http://www.ibm.com/software/htp/cics/annotations">#Wed Sep 14 08:27:59 BST 2005
com.ibm.cics.wsdl.properties.synchronized=false
</xsd:appinfo>
                                       </xsd:annotation>
                                       <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                          <xsd:maxLength value="40"/>
                                          <xsd:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
                                       </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                 </xsd:element>
                                 <xsd:element name="ca_sngl_department" nillable="false">
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                       <xsd:annotation>
                                          <xsd:appinfo source="http://www.ibm.com/software/htp/cics/annotations">#Wed Sep 14 08:27:59 BST 2005
com.ibm.cics.wsdl.properties.synchronized=false
</xsd:appinfo>
                                       </xsd:annotation>
                                       <xsd:restriction base="xsd:unsignedShort">
                                          <xsd:maxInclusive value="999"/>
                                          <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                       </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                 </xsd:element>
                                 <xsd:element name="ca_sngl_cost" nillable="false">
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                       <xsd:annotation>
                                          <xsd:appinfo source="http://www.ibm.com/software/htp/cics/annotations">#Wed Sep 14 08:28:00 BST 2005
com.ibm.cics.wsdl.properties.synchronized=false
</xsd:appinfo>
                                       </xsd:annotation>
                                       <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                          <xsd:maxLength value="6"/>
                                          <xsd:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
                                       </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                 </xsd:element>
                                 <xsd:element name="in_sngl_stock" nillable="false">
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                       <xsd:annotation>
                                          <xsd:appinfo source="http://www.ibm.com/software/htp/cics/annotations">#Wed Sep 14 08:28:00 BST 2005
com.ibm.cics.wsdl.properties.synchronized=false
</xsd:appinfo>
                                       </xsd:annotation>
                                       <xsd:restriction base="xsd:unsignedShort">
                                          <xsd:maxInclusive value="9999"/>
                                          <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                       </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                 </xsd:element>
                                 <xsd:element name="on_sngl_order" nillable="false">
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                       <xsd:annotation>
                                          <xsd:appinfo source="http://www.ibm.com/software/htp/cics/annotations">#Wed Sep 14 08:28:01 BST 2005
com.ibm.cics.wsdl.properties.synchronized=false
</xsd:appinfo>
                                       </xsd:annotation>
                                       <xsd:restriction base="xsd:unsignedShort">
                                          <xsd:maxInclusive value="999"/>
                                          <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                       </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                 </xsd:element>
                              </xsd:sequence>
                           </xsd:complexType>
                        </xsd:element>
                     </xsd:sequence>
                  </xsd:complexType>
               </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
         </xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:element name="DFH0XCMNOperationResponse" nillable="false" type="tns:ProgramInterface"/>
      </xsd:schema>
   </types>
   <message name="DFH0XCMNOperationResponse">
      <part element="resns:DFH0XCMNOperationResponse" name="ResponsePart"/>
   </message>
   <message name="DFH0XCMNOperationRequest">
      <part element="reqns:DFH0XCMNOperation" name="RequestPart"/>
   </message>
   <portType name="DFH0XCMNPort">
      <operation name="DFH0XCMNOperation">
         <input message="tns:DFH0XCMNOperationRequest" name="DFH0XCMNOperationRequest"/>
         <output message="tns:DFH0XCMNOperationResponse" name="DFH0XCMNOperationResponse"/>
      </operation>
   </portType>
   <binding name="DFH0XCMNHTTPSoapBinding" type="tns:DFH0XCMNPort">
      <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
      <operation name="DFH0XCMNOperation">
         <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
         <input name="DFH0XCMNOperationRequest">
            <soap:body parts="RequestPart" use="literal"/>
         </input>
         <output name="DFH0XCMNOperationResponse">
            <soap:body parts="ResponsePart" use="literal"/>
         </output>
      </operation>
   </binding>
   <service name="DFH0XCMNService">
      <port binding="tns:DFH0XCMNHTTPSoapBinding" name="DFH0XCMNPort">
         <soap:address location="http://my-server:my-port/exampleApp/inquireSingle"/>
      </port>
   </service>
</definitions>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is seems that WL v6.1 indeed has a problem with multiple embedded schemas and showing only one the input of a procedure. The output of the procedure is not being shown because it is defined by a second embedded schema.

This problem was addressed and tested using your WSDL with a newer version of WL (not yet released). You will therefore get it solved in the next update of your Worklight Studio.

If you are an IBM business partner or customer you can open a PMR and request an intermittent iFix.